# Ideal Turbulence

Tags: fluid-dynamics, symmetry, turbulence, oceanography

I'm studying the turbulence in ocean and i started to study a mathematic introduction of turbulence.

We define

$ R_{ij}(\underline{x},\underline{r},t) := \overline{u_i(\underline{x},t)u_j(\underline{x}+\underline{r},t)}$

Assuming an ideal turbulence, that is an homogeneous, stationary, isotropic Turbulence
, i.e

- $R_{ij}(\underline{x},\underline{r},t) = R_{ij}(\underline{x} + \underline{\gamma},\underline{r},t)\quad$ for all $\underline{\gamma} \in R^3$
- $R_{ij}(\underline{x},\underline{r},t) = R_{ij}(\underline{x} ,\underline{r},t+ \gamma)\quad$ for all $\gamma \in R$
- ISOTROPY CONDITION

For the first two condition we derive that
$R_{ij}(\underline{x},\underline{r},t) = R_{ij}(\underline{r})$

Now i don't understand the isotropy condition.
According to me it means that

$R_{ij}(D\underline{r}) = R_{ij}(\underline{r}) \quad $ for all D rotation matrix

If it is the correct condition, why and how i can obtain that $R_{ij}$ is of the following form

$R_{ij}(\underline{r}) = A(|\underline{r}|)\delta_{ij} + B(|\underline{r}|)r_ir_j$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wrote down is the most general isotropic two-point tensor of rank two. It is derived geometrically.

Define the correlation tensor as

$$\overline{u^2} R_{ij} = \overline{u_i u_j'}. $$

We now consider the correlation between a component of the velocity $\mathbf{u}$ at location $P$ and a component of the velocity $\mathbf{u}'$ at location $P'$. Consider further some arbitrary direction cosines $a_i$ at $P$ and $b_i$ at $P'$. Then the correlation is:

$$\overline{u^2} R(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}) = \overline{a_i u_i b_j u_j'} = \overline{u_i u_j'}a_i b_j. $$

Using the correlation tensor definition from above, this implies that

$$R(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})=R_{i j} a_{i} b_{j}. $$

We now mandate that $R(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$ be invariant under arbitrary translation or rotation of the unit vectors $a_i$, $b_i$, or the distance between the two points $P$ and $P'$. We label the distance between the two points as $r_i$.

It is true from the theory of rotation groups that we can decompose any invariant function as a sum of "fundamental invariants" of the individual vectors $r_i, a_i, b_i$. The fundamental invariants are

1. any scalar product of the individual vectors like $r_i a_i, \,a_i b_i,\ldots$ etc.
2. the determinant of any three vectors such as $\epsilon_{ijk} r_i a_j b_k$       (where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)).

(We will shortly see that 2. is not necessary.) At most, $R(\mathbf{r}; \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$ can be a function of the six scalar products of 1 and the single determinant of 2. However, we already showed that $R$ must be a homogenous function, linear in both vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. At most, then, this function can be written as

$$R(\mathbf{r} ; \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})=A(\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{a})(\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{b})+B(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b})+C\det(\mathbf{r} \mathbf{a b})$$

for some arbitrary radial functions $A,B,C$. Comparing this to $\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})=R_{i j} a_{i} b_{j}$, the coefficient $R_{ij}$ must be

$$R_{i j}=A r_{i} r_{j}+B \delta_{i j}+C \epsilon_{i j k} r_{k} $$

where $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i=j$, and vanishes otherwise. Finally, we require that $R_{ij}$ be symmetric such that $$R_{ij} = R_{ji}$$ and so we must force $C=0$, since $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is antisymmetric under exchange $i \leftrightarrow j$. Thus $$R_{i j}=A r_{i} r_{j}+B \delta_{i j}$$ as you state.

**Source**:  H. P. Robertson, *[The invariant theory of isotropic turbulence](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/invariant-theory-of-isotropic-turbulence/20D2B827EAE1BA8EFDBD0AEB7069A059)*.